# How to create a Line With Gaps Follower? [Robotc] [LegoMindstorm][EV3]

Tags: algorithm, robotics, lego-mindstorms, robotc

Trying to create an algorithm/code in order to get my robot to follow a track which it currently can do, using a color sensor and following the inside edge. So I'm wondering how to transition to the track with broken parts the track has gaps with a max length of 20cm and only on straight parts. I also have a distance sensor available? any ideas?